# Spring MVC - missing variable from URI named "path"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I have created application from [Jhipster's](https://jhipster.github.io/) template,
I have changed almost nothing in the project and it's working fine on local machine but when I deploy it to my server (ubuntu, apache, tomcat - all are the last versions) weird things start to happen.

I have AJAX call to "/api/account" which on local machine get's in response the following json

```
{
    "timestamp":1440703613150,
    "status":401,
    "error":"Unauthorized",
    "message":"Access Denied",
    "path":"/api/account"
}
```

and on the production server (you can check it [here](http://213.133.98.210/#/)) same call get's json WITHOUT "path" field in it

```
{
    "timestamp":1440703613150,
    "status":401,
    "error":"Unauthorized",
    "message":"Access Denied"
}
```

I stuck on this for long period of time, so, please help me if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have an Apache front-end, have a look at your mod_http_proxy settings, `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`.
You should also have a look at your Apache logs.

Or disable Apache and access JHipster directly, so you know if this is caused by Apache or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why this would be an issue.

Your setup is probably different somehow, if you want to have same setup the best is to use the executable jar embedding TOmcat rather than deploying it to a server.

Are you running in prod profile for both your local machine and production server?

Comment: Hi Gaël, thank you for your answer.

Yes, I'm running in prod profile for both, but the result is the same, everything works great on local machine and on remote server "path" is missing from response.
As far as I can see the only difference between them is tomcat configuration, but i cannot understand how can tomcat cause such issue.

Comment: But why is it important for you?

Comment: it causes infinite loop in javascript logic

there is a piece of code

if (response.status == 401 && response.data.path!="/api/account") {
// log out and redirect to login page
}

when response.data.path is undefined it causes browser to recall /api/account and here starts infinite loop, 
I have modified code and after status check have added "&& response.data.path" but it seems to be temporary and ugly workaround.

Comment: OK, so you should run your prod app under debugger.

Comment: Thank you Gaël, I'll try what you suggest.